# Who is responsible for freeing the memory of Singleton class in iOS?

Tags: ios5, ios4

I am checking on how to write Singleton class on iOS. According to the web site (http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/), I understand that without the use of ARC, I need to use allocWithZone function to allocate my class itself.

My key question is ... how can the memory of my class (after alloc or allocWithZone) be freed later ? Who is responsible for the memory ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to "free the memory" during `-(id) init` you can set `self = nil;`